# How to make connections between application and barcode reader?

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner

I want to get input from barcode reader in specific text box which is disabled I don’t have any idea to do something so I have few problems

1. I need the library name which .Net framework has for barcode scanner
2. how can I get the input from barcode scanner in a specific text box which is already disabled and also it is visibility is false

Comment: If it supports it configure the scanner as a *keyboard wedge* then it will simply send keystrokes for the decoded barcode that you can then capture in the parent windows key events.

Comment: _"I need the library name which .Net framework has for barcode scanner"_ I don't think there is one. Most scanners will just emulate an input device.

Comment: When I had to get information from a barcode reader, I just put a textbox in a location the user can't see (beyond what the screen can show) and had it focused and enabled. The barcode reader mimic typing into the textbox. Worked perfectly.

Comment: You normally don't need any library, input from Barcode Scanner is received as Keyboard input, for special setup, your scanner should come with a printed setup manual.

Comment: The barcode reader gives input in the textbox which has focus but  I want to get the input in a specific text box even it doesn’t have focus.   Is this possible?

Comment: You can always set the text of the other textbox programatically, even if it's disabled...

Comment: How I can set it I don’t have any idea

Comment: One question, will it scan and only show the information or the user must type something after it has scanned the code ?! if its only to Scan and show, you could put the focus on a textbox that is hidden from user view and on enter receive (the scanner it will send a enter at the end) fill the information and clear and focus on it again ?

Comment: You can use the Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 library. Many scanners support both HID mode (keyboard emulation) and a serial mode. Have a look at your scanners users guide. If it supports the serial mode, switch your scanner to that mode (typically by scanning a barcode from that users guide) and also turn on the OPOS mode, if required. But this depends on your scanner model. If your scanner is correctly configured, you can register on the  `Microsoft.PointOfService.Scanner.DataEvent` event to receive scanned barcode data. See the POS for .NET samples and documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you need more than just keyboard wedge input from barcode scanners in your application, you might try the Pos for .Net SDK. With it, you can control POS devices directly. You may have to re-configure barcode scanners as a HID BarcodeScanner, instead of as a keyboard.  You can find the SDK at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55758